# how can i insert more than 200 entries into plist at once?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, plist

I am working on a project in which i have already created the plist  which is having more than 200 items in it ,but now the problem is i need to add another key and its corresponding value to each of the items. I have an excel sheet which has the value for that key , Is there a way to get that values of excel sheet into my plist other than manually adding them one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the Excel File in CSV then use that CSV file to extract data into pList.